# Postgresql WalReceiver process waits on connecting master regardless of "connect_timeout"

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, tcp

I am trying to deploy an automated high-available PostgreSQL cluster on kubernetes. In cases of master failover or temporary failures in master, standby loses streaming replication connection and when retrying, it takes a long time until it gets failed and retries.

I use PostgreSQL 10 and streaming replication (`cluster-main-cluster-master-service` is a service that always routes to master and all the replicas connect to this service for replication). I've tried setting configs like `connect_timeout` and `keepalive` in `primary_conninfo` of `recovery.conf` and `wal_receiver_timeout` in `postgresql.conf` of standby but I could not make any progress with them.

In the first place when master goes down, replication stops with the following error (state 1):

```
2019-10-06 14:14:54.042 +0330 [3039] LOG:  replication terminated by primary server
2019-10-06 14:14:54.042 +0330 [3039] DETAIL:  End of WAL reached on timeline 17 at 0/33000098.
2019-10-06 14:14:54.042 +0330 [3039] FATAL:  could not send end-of-streaming message to primary: no COPY in progress
2019-10-06 14:14:55.534 +0330 [12] LOG:  record with incorrect prev-link 0/2D000028 at 0/33000098
```

After investigating Postgres activities I found out that WalReceiver proccess stucks in `LibPQWalReceiverConnect` wait_event (state 2) but timeout is way longer than what I configured (although I set `connect_timeout` to 10 seconds, it takes about 2 minutes). Then, It fails with the following error (state 3):

```
2019-10-06 14:17:06.035 +0330 [3264] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "cluster-main-cluster-master-service" (192.168.0.166) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

In the next try, It successfully connects the primary (state 4):

```
2019-10-06 14:17:07.892 +0330 [5786] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/33000000 on timeline 17
```

I also tried killing the process when stuck event occurs (state 2), and when I do, It starts the process again and connects and then streams normally (jumps to state 4).

After checking netstat, I also found that there is a connection with `SYN_SENT` state to the old master in the walreceiver process (in failover case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`connect_timeout` governs how long PostgreSQL will wait for the replication connection to succeed, but that does not include establishing the TCP connection.

To reduce the time that the kernel waits for a successful answer to a TCP SYN request, reduce the number of retries. In `/etc/sysctl.conf`, set:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 3
```

and run `sysctl -p`.

That should reduce the time significantly.

Reducing the value too much might make your system less stable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I have tried this and it works well and the time gets reduced. But I was worried about what consequences and side-effects this could have on the whole system. 
Also I believed there should be an application level timeout which sets a timeout regardless of which step the procedure stands. (No matter the connection is established or not)

Comment: You could raise that as a PostgreSQL bug if you think the behavior is surprising.